# Bubbles in a Pipeline 2

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, bubbles

This question has kind of been asked before [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76016/bubble-in-a-pipeline?newreg=38cf0cc044c84c10801b475211ef59d1), but aren't the gas bubbles in the pipeline also a moving fluid and so as they get constricted shouldn't their pressure decrease too.  If so how are the pressure of the water and gas related?  That is, if both decrease in pressure can't the bubbles remain the same size?

Comment: You are getting into an area known as two phase flow.  There are several regimes of two phase flow, and the physics behind those regimes is somewhat complicated.  What fraction of the flow is bubbles?  Do the bubbles ever coalesce into larger bubbles or get split into smaller bubbles?  Is the flow horizontal, vertical, or slanted?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be talking about the Bernoulli Effect. The fact that they are moving doesn't mean their pressure decreases. They are just being carried along, like in a vehicle. As the water approaches the constriction, apart from friction with the wall, the pressure will be higher because the water has to accelerate, so the bubbles will be compressed. Once in the constriction, the water pressure will be less, and will keep reducing, as there is less pipe in front to cause friction. The Bernoulli Effect is the fluid carrying surrounding fluid away with it, leaving a low pressure zone. Unless it passes a T junction, there will only be pipe wall, so the only thing that should change the pressure, is the change in friction as there is less & less pipe in front. If the constriction was a s small straight sided pipe & was frictionless, the pressure inside would be atmospheric pressure and the bubbles will be normal size.